# Looking for a good C# exception logging tool

Tags: c#, exception, logging, reporting

I got an exception in a program that I tested for someone. The program is written in Delphi and uses a nice exception logging tool named [madExcept](http://www.madcodehook.com/madExceptDescription.htm). It allows exception reporting of the user's system, a stack trace and so on.

Is there a pendant for C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EurekaLog](http://www.eurekalog.com/index_dotnet.php) has .net and Delphi versions.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html). It's really flexible and widespread.

NOTE: This is valid if you design the application from ground up in regards to logging.

Answer (score 2):

NLog is also a good option http://www.nlog-project.org

Answer (score 1):

We have been using [Gurock Smart Inspect](http://www.gurock.com/smartinspect/) a lot where I work, and that is a very good program (not free of shareware though).

You can easily set the level of logging, and also get it to make a more detailed logging just before a exception happens, so it's easy to track it down.

I recommend downloading a trial version and try it out.

Comment: How do you get it to do a more detailed logging just before an exception occurs?

Comment: I guess it logs details internally all the time, but only output according to the level you have set it to do, but if an exception occurs, it "steps back" and output more detailed logging in the time just before the exception occured.

Answer (score 0):

[Crypto Logger](http://www.ssware.com/cryptologger/logger-net.htm) can log exceptions using a special LogException method which you can then see (including the message and stack trace) in its Console.

Answer (score 0):

[SmartAssembly](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/) by RedGate has [automated error reporting](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/smartassembly/features/#automated-error-reporting) apart from being an obfuscator. It also has feature usage functionality. The tool is commercial though.